# Getting error "invalid predicate" in lxml when using xpath

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I have an xml file which contains shows. I want to have an xpath query to get one entry from this xml.

When querying the xml with tools like QXmlEdit and Xmplify and the following query: `//sendung[standard/stammdaten/metadaten/idnr[text() = '11223344' ]]`
i receive exactly the result i'm expecting. The same query on python 3.7 with lxml does not work.

```
root.findall(".//dmb:sendung[dmb:standard/dmb:stammdaten/dmb:metadaten/dmb:idnr[text()='{}']]".format(id), namespaces=self.__namespace_map)
```

the error i get is `SyntaxError: invalid predicate`

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe `findall()` is limited in what XPath can be used (basically the same limitations as ElementTree). Try using `xpath()` instead of `findall()`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use the `xpath()` method. `findall()` [does not support](https://lxml.de/FAQ.html#xpath-and-document-traversal) all  of XPath 1.0. In your expression, there are two features that don't work:

- Nested predicates.
- The `text()` node test.